# Sum of squares for a Dirichlet distribution

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, dirichlet-distribution

I have some data that takes the form of vectors $(a_0,...,a_n)$ lying on the simplex $\Sigma a_i = 1$ (all $a_i$'s non-negative). I have noticed that the maximum $\max_i a_i$ is very highly correlated with the sum of squares $\Sigma a_i^2$. What could be an explanation for that? In particular, is this something one would expect if the sample was taken from a Dirichlet distribution? I have tried to search online for information about it, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple: Since a Dirichlet distributed random variable is a random vector with non-negative components summing to 1, especially if the max is close to 1, there is not much contribution left from the rest of the components. If the vector dimension is large this effect must be more profound.

Below is some R code to experiment:

```r
library(extraDistr)
alpha <- rep(1, 10)

X <- rdirichlet(1000, alpha)

sq <- apply(X, 1, function(x) sum(x*x) )
ma <- apply(X, 1, function(x) max(x) ) 

cor(sq, ma)
[1] 0.9292814
```

[image]

For exploring this more theoretically, this [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.4059.pdf) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When you square the $a_i$, the largest value dominates the smaller ones even more after they are squared, because for $0 < x < 1$, that $x^2 < x$.

For example, suppose $n=1$.  If $a_0 = 0.6$ and $a_1 = 0.4$ the sum of squares is $0.36 + 0.16 = 0.52$, with the max $a_0$ making by far the largest contribution.

If instead we have $a_0 = 0.8$ and $a_1 = 0.2$ then the sum of squares is $0.64 + 0.04 = 0.68$, with even greater domination by $a_0$.

So the largest $a_i$ dominates the sum of squares, and dominates more and more as the value of $a_i$ increases.